# I need senders email id in email subject

Tags: php

My php script is running well but i want to send senders address in email subject .Please guide me how to do it.

Please tell me what should i write in "$emailSbuject = "New Subscription from $emailFeild\r\n";"

This is my php script:

```
<?php
/* subject and email varialbles*/

$emailSbuject = "New Subscription from $emailFeild\r\n";
$webMaster = 'help@sample.com';
$emailSbuject2 = 'Thank you';
$client = ' $emailFeild\r\n';
/*gathering data variables*/

$emailFeild = $_POST['email'];

// admin message body
$body= <<<EOD
New subscriber is $emailFeild

EOD;

$textMessage = <<<EOD

<p style="margin-left:5px;font-family:Calibri"><img alt=""         src="http://www.intaxfin.com/images/Intaxfin_logo.png"></p>

         <p style="font-family:Calibri">Thank you for subscribing with us. Somebody will get back     to you as soon as possible.</p>

<p  style="font-size:x-small;color:#0099FF;font-family:Calibri">This e-mail was automatically     sent by Administration Directory and is for your reference. Please do not reply to this e-    mail address.<br>
Powered by sample</p>

EOD;
    $headers = "From: $emailFeild\r\n";
    $header = "From: $noreply@sample.com\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html;     charset=utf-8\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster,$emailSbuject,$body,$headers);
    $success1 = @mail($emailFeild,$emailSbuject2,$textMessage,$header);
    /*Result*/

    $theResults = <<<EOD
EOD;

echo  "$theResults";

header("Location: thankyousubscribe.html");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: `$emailSbuject = "New Subscription from ".$emailFeild."\r\n";`

Comment: @Bowdzone thnx sir. its working absoluely fine. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 $emailFeild = $_POST['email'];
 $emailSbuject2 = "New Subscription from $emailFeild";
```

NOTE : $client has been initiated with $emailFeild variable which is initiated after that line. Please initiate the variable first and then use it.

Comment: My Answer was selected and now I dont know why it has revoked and I have downvoted...

Comment: sorry your code is not working. @bowdzone gave the right answer.